# Flask Flatpages list of folders. BuildError

Tags: python, flask, flask-flatpages

I'm using Flask with `Flask-FlatPages` and I'm trying to get a list of all the subdirectories in the Flatpages `/pages` folder. These folders should appear as a link that when clicked append the foldername on the url. In the pages folder are two subdirectories: misc and test. I have tried this:

```
@app.route('/list')
def listdir():
    folders = os.listdir('./pages')
    return render_template('list.html', folders=folders)
```

and the template is using this part:

```
<ul class="unstyled">
{% for folder in folders %}
    <li>
    <a href="{{ url_for("folder", name=folder) }}"><h3>{{ folder }}</h3></a>
    </li>
 ....
```

but it just gives me an empty page.

i have tried a bit and now it gives me at least an error:

```
BuildError: ('folder', {'name': 'test'}, None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this BuildError, Flask is telling you that it can not find the URL for a view named "folder" that takes a single "name" parameter. Do you have such a view? Please provide all of your views’ code.

Comment: I just got the name in the linked view wrong, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to alternate single and double quotes in your template use; instead of `"{{ url_for("folder", name=folder) }}"` you need `'{{ url_for("folder", name=folder) }}'`.
2. While testing and developing your application, add `debug=True` to your run statement. This adds error pages with *very* nice debugging tools: `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=10000, debug=True)`